# Any freely available Magento 2 theme's that demonstrate current best practices?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Any freely available Magento 2 theme's that demonstrate the 2.3 best practices?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/theme-best-practice.html

Ideally a theme that modifies the header, footer, and navigation, but even one of those done properly might help.

Just to clarify, that means a theme that inherits from blank.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried them myself, but if you are searching for some good boilerplates regarding frontend best practices, you might want to have a look at the work of Snowdog Apps:

Sass replacement Theme for blank theme:
https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass

Complete replacement of frontend components:
https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-alpaca-theme

Comment: Not really appropriate choices for a first theme.  Also SASS has been officially rebuked by upstream, creating a new theme that isn't LESS is bare minimum a risky idea.  You kinda need to know the flaws in the present practices, before you could know when doing something totally different is a good idea.

Also the stock front end tools are far more than adequate, and the blank theme provides the tool set almost pre-configured.  I'm looking for how the common modifications are supposed to be done, as described in the docs.

Comment: The stock front-end tools are terrible especially when compared to modern front-end tooling.

Comment: hehe, I personally agree with both of you. On the one hand, using the given standard is a good Idea because of the reasons you described. Small changes can (mostly) be implemented really fast and you get upgrades / feature completeness. But specific changes can require a very deep knowledge of magentos knockout.js / ui components implementation. So, on the other hand, depending on your developers, workflows and the project itself, it can definitely be a good idea to build on something like the snowdog projects or even build something completely new.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this theme, which was created for part of a series of you tube theme tutorial videos.  The modifications are done in a modern way, and in line with best practices, going to use for my start.

The theme is at,
https://github.com/mcspronko/magento-2-pronko-consulting-theme

The tutorial vids are on his youtube channel, 
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxbWGz6h6KNQsi2ughRUV2Q